# How to set this.getAttribute('href') in this javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to load a link after 4 seconds after click. Javascript and link are below

```
 <script>
 function myFunction()
 {
 setTimeout(function(){window.location.assign(this.getAttribute('href'))},4000);
 }
 </script>

<a href="http://www.foo.com" onclick="myFunction(); return false">
```

But its not working. How can i solve this. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Why do you want to do this and break how browsers work, including Ctrl-click?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass the clicked element reference to the click handler

```
<a href="http://www.foo.com" onclick="myFunction(this); return false">
```

then

```
function myFunction(el) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.assign(el.getAttribute('href'))
    }, 4000);
}
```

or using jQuery

```
function myFunction(el) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.assign($(el).attr('href'))
    }, 4000);
}
```

Comment: Spot on answer, although I would have omitted the jQuery version (unnecessary, isn't it?)